# PredictionIO 0.12.1 - No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting

Tags: predictionio

I have used Binary Distribution to install PredictionIO 0.12.1, I have successfully started pio. After that I have used Quick Start - E-Commerce Recommendation Engine Template. At the time of building, I am getting Error that  "[ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting."

```
fh@fh:~/fh_engines/MyECommerceRecommendation$ pio build --verbose
[INFO] [Engine$] Using command '/home/fh/PredictionIO-0.12.1/sbt/sbt' at /home/fh/fh_engines/MyECommerceRecommendation to build.
[INFO] [Engine$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Engine$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.12.1.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Engine$] Going to run: /home/fh/PredictionIO-0.12.1/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency in /home/fh/fh_engines/MyECommerceRecommendation
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Loading project definition from /home/fh/.sbt/0.13/staging/a8733a2463247b8ef5ff/myecommercerecommendation/project
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Set current project to template-scala-parallel-ecommercerecommendation (in build file:/home/fh/fh_engines/MyECommerceRecommendation/)
[INFO] [Engine$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed 21 May, 2018 10:42:05 AM
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Including from cache: scala-library-2.11.8.jar
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Merging files...
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Assembly up to date: /home/fh/.sbt/0.13/staging/a8733a2463247b8ef5ff/myecommercerecommendation/target/scala-2.11/template-scala-parallel-ecommercerecommendation-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar
[INFO] [Engine$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed 21 May, 2018 10:42:06 AM
[INFO] [Engine$] Compilation finished successfully.
[INFO] [Engine$] Looking for an engine...
[ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
fh@fh:~/fh_engines/MyECommerceRecommendation$
```

Comment: Did you miss the step of downloading an engine and setting up `engine.json`? It is source hosted on GitHub somewhere, depending on the Engine you are using.

Comment: Nope. I have downloaded the engine properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with a binary distribution, I have downloaded the source and build the binary with required dependency.

It was a permission issue. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I need to provide the read permission to particular template folder ( in this case MyECommerceRecommendation)

After giving permission, it was working fine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify engine instance id while deploying which you can get by greping EngineInstaceId after training is complete.